# Request in Laravel for my function index()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a problem with my function index() concerning a request. In fact, I have to adapt my old function with a recent.

For information,  my function index() (old) below was written like this and it works !!

```
public function index(Request $req) 
    {

    if ($req->search == "") {
        $retours = Retour::join('eleves', 'retours.fk_eleve', '=', 'eleves.id')->orderBy('eleves.nom', 'asc')->select('retours.*')->paginate(5);
        return view('admin.retours.index', compact('retours'));

    } else {

        $validated = $req->validate([
            'search' => 'alpha', 
        ]);

        $retours = Retour::join('eleves', 'retours.fk_eleve', '=', 'eleves.id')->where('eleves.nom','like', '%' . $req->search . '%')->orderBy('eleves.nom', 'asc')->select('retours.*')->paginate(5);

        return view('admin.retours.index', compact('retours'));
        }

    }
```

Now, I have to change a party of code and I must to adapt my request:

```
$retours = Retour::join('eleves', 'retours.fk_eleve', '=', 'eleves.id')->where('eleves.nom','like', '%' . $req->search . '%')->orderBy('eleves.nom', 'asc')->select('retours.*')->paginate(5);
```

Here is an idea of my new code, my problem is that the search bar doesn't filter ? ^^

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {   
        $user = $request->user();

        $retours = Retour::query()
        ->when($user->hasRole('admin') !== true, function (Builder $query) use ($user) {
            $query->where('email', $user->email);
        })
        ->when($request->has('search'), function (Builder $query) use ($request) {
         $query->join('eleves', 'retours.fk_eleve', '=', 'eleves.id')->orderBy('eleves.nom', 'asc')->select('retours.*');
        })
        ->paginate(5);

        return view('admin.retours.index', compact('retours'))
            ->with('display_search', $user->hasRole('admin'));
    }
```

My problem is perhaps here ?

```
->when($request->has('search'), function (Builder $query) use ($request) {
         $query->join('eleves', 'retours.fk_eleve', '=', 'eleves.id')->orderBy('eleves.nom', 'asc')->select('retours.*');
        })
        ->paginate(5);
```

Do have you an idea please?

Thank you

Comment: You're missing the where clause in your new code: `where('eleves.nom','like', '%' . $req->search . '%')`

Comment: @Bryan: Yesssss, thank you Bryan it works . ^^

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.